# Create an Hadoop Archive (HAR) from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, archive

Is there a way to create an Hadoop archive (HAR) using the Java API ?

In this page, it is explained how to create an Hadoop Archive (HAR) from an existing HDFS directory within the shell : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-archives/HadoopArchives.html

I want to do the same using the Java API, which is documented here : http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/HarFileSystem.html

However, it looks like that there's no method to create a new archive from this documentation. I have already looked at the initialize method but it requires an existing archive.

Comment: You probably want to use the class: org.apache.hadoop.tools.HadoopArchives

Comment: @JFPicard There is no such class mentioned in the documentation. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.1/api/index.html